# Mongoose extract specific section of a big document

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

For those who stumble upon this post in the future. The result for use was simply that a 4.5mb doc in mongodb is simple too big for efficient read/write. We figured out a way to reduce the doc size to approx 0.2mb per doc. Need speed with mongo querying... don't let the doc size get over approx. 0.5mb

---

I have a small set of documents (approx. 500) in mongodb where each doc is 4-6mb.

The database is for a sport events.

The schema for the doc looks like (trimmed down):

```
const schema = {
  _id: {type: String, default: uuidv1},
  layoutName: String,
  contests: [
    {
      externalId: String,
      thirdPartyEventId: String,
      name: String,
      rounds: [
        {
          _id: {type: String, default: uuidv1},
          thirdPartyId: String,
          externalId: String,
          heats: [
            {
              externalId: String,
              name: String,
              order: Number,
              categories: [
                {
                  key: String,
                  label: String,
                },
              ],
              runs: [
                {
                  thirdPartyId: String,
                  externalId: String,
                  name: String,
                  order: Number,
                },
              ],
            },
          ],
        },
      ],
    },
  ],
}
```

Currently the app is fetching an entire object by _id, then extracting a heat with lodash but this is taking a considerable amount of time (around 400ms) as the doc holds so much data.

I am trying to see if the database layer will be quicker, but my mongo query skills are a little rusty. How would I write a query using mongoose to extract a specific section of a document. I was trying to query the collection of docs with:

```
{
  "_id": "ead08850-c313-11e8-8f9a-f7563bcfbf40",
  "contests.externalId": "Timing1",
  "contests.rounds.externalId": "Timing5",
  "contests.rounds.heats.externalId": "Timing21"
}
```

But the response is empty.

The above object is a path to the heat i need to fetch.. am I approaching this in the wrong way?

PS/
Currently the to extract the right heat:

```
const contest = find(event.contests, {externalId: contestId})
if (!contest) {
  return false
}
const round = find(contest.rounds, {externalId: roundId})
if (!round) {
  return false
}
return find(round.heats, {externalId: heatId})
```

Comment: Can you post sample data? Your `find` query structure looks ok.

Comment: the find query works just fine, the the finds take approx 20ms. The biggest time is extracting the giant 4.5mb document from the mongodb collection (on ave 500ms). So i was wondering if mongodb could filter what i need faster than post query work.

Comment: Which part exactly are you trying to get ... the `heats` only?

Comment: yes but only where the above "externalId" match the provided values as "heats" is an array of many heats within and array of many "rounds" within an array of many "contests".. my lodash "find" functions work and work fast but extracting the full doc from the database is the slow link i am trying to improve

Answer (score 0):

Try using aggregation an then [**$filter**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/index.html) like this:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      "_id": 1,
      "contests.rounds.heats.externalId": 5
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$contests"
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$contests.rounds"
  },
  {
    $project: {
      "_id": 0,
      "contests": {
        $filter: {
          input: "$contests.rounds.heats",
          as: "item",
          cond: {
            $eq: ["$$item.externalId", 5]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

See it [working here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/YEMhGZOsFR2)

Comment: this still needs post query work, but also returns all heats in a full document, which includes heats from other rounds and rounds from other contests.

Comment: Can you post the `exact` output you are after please?

Comment: I only see one heat based on the sample data I used here: https://mongoplayground.net/p/yPj3UDiyhCg

Comment: Wow, that is amazing tool!! I took you data and tweaked it:  https://mongoplayground.net/p/KmUeNaqn_68  What i am aiming for in the sample data is 1 heat where: `"_id":1` & `"contests.externalId":2` & `"contests.rounds.externalId":2` & `"contests.rounds.heats.externalId": 5`

Comment: it is like i need to use the projection but where the projection matches a value...

Comment: See if the aggregation example works. I updated the answer with a demo as well.

Comment: Massive thanks for your help. Unfortunately, even with aggregation queries the read/write time was too slow for this application. We needed to retain the multikey querying and still need a db that can run locally and in the cloud.. so we figured out a way to reduce the doc size to something much much smaller which led to a much faster read/write time